# Function to mutate a number of rows in a tibble, taking the number of rows from another tibble

Tags: r, function, output, purrr, dplyr

i'm looking to do something which looks simple, but can't get the output i want

I have a bunch of observation with day, categorie and colour

```
   observations <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1596585600, 1596585600, 1596585600, 
    1596585600, 1596585600, 1596585600, 1596585600, 1596672000, 1596672000, 
    1596672000, 1596758400, 1596758400, 1596758400, 1596758400, 1596758400
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), categorie = c("dog", 
    "dog", "dog", "wolf", "wolf", "wolf", "wolf", "dog", "dog", "wolf", 
    "dog", "wolf", "wolf", "wolf", "wolf"), color = c("blue", "blue", 
    "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "darkred", "darkred", 
    "darkred", "darkred", "darkred", "darkred", "darkred", "darkred"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
```

I want to change the colour attribute following a tibble with the number of colour i want to change by day and category

```
howmanyrainbowsiwant <-structure(list(date = structure(c(1596585600, 1596758400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), categorie = c("dog", "wolf"), makeitrainbow = c(2, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

In this example i want to change :

- Two randomly choosen dogs observations on 05/08/2020 to "rainbow"
- Two randomly choosen wolf obersvations on 07/08/2020 to "rainbow"

I tried purr:mappp, purr:walk, and "<<-" to make it global but when i run the function and count the color, i can't see any rainbow .... Outside the function it seems to work ..

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)


coloriage<- function(x) {
    
              current <- tibble(x) ## make the row a variable
       tirage<-current$makeitrainbow[1] ## Making the number of rainbow i want a variable
      # I take a sample/slice of the datasource with the number of rainbow i want 
    
      petitsample <- observations %>%
        filter(categorie %in% current$categorie ) %>%
        filter(date %in% current$date ) %>%
         slice_sample(tirage)
      
    ## then i save the lines in the main data but not in the slice
      temp <- setdiff(observations , petitsample)
    
    ## I change the color value of the splice rows
      petitsample<- petitsample %>% mutate(color= "rainbow")
      
    ## I bring back together the non modified rows and the splice modified rows
    # trying with "<<-"
      observations <<- bind_rows(temp, petitsample)
    ## And tryng with return
      return(observations )
    }
    
    ## Using function
     walk(howmanyrainbowsiwant , coloriage) 
    
    ## Checking if it worked (looking for "rainbow " values)
    
    observations %>% count(color)
    
    ## and it fails ...
```

Thanks !!

ps :looks like there may be an error in my reprex too, but cannot find ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a two step procedure. First compute the indices of the rows to change, and then change the original dataframe at these positions (using base R - tidyverse is nt so well suited for this change).

```
library(tidyverse)

## compute rows to be changed
inds_to_change <-
  pmap(howmanyrainbowsiwant,
     function(date, categorie, makeitrainbow)
         sample(
                which(observations$date == date &
                      observations$categorie == categorie),
                makeitrainbow)
     ) %>% 
  unlist()

## change color in these rows
observations$color[inds_to_change] <- "rainbow"
observations
```

Result (can be different at your compute due to random selection of rows)

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
   date                categorie color  
   <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>  
 1 2020-08-05 00:00:00 dog       blue   
 2 2020-08-05 00:00:00 dog       rainbow
 3 2020-08-05 00:00:00 dog       rainbow
 4 2020-08-05 00:00:00 wolf      blue   
 5 2020-08-05 00:00:00 wolf      blue   
 6 2020-08-05 00:00:00 wolf      blue   
 7 2020-08-05 00:00:00 wolf      blue   
 8 2020-08-06 00:00:00 dog       darkred
 9 2020-08-06 00:00:00 dog       darkred
10 2020-08-06 00:00:00 wolf      darkred
11 2020-08-07 00:00:00 dog       darkred
12 2020-08-07 00:00:00 wolf      rainbow
13 2020-08-07 00:00:00 wolf      darkred
14 2020-08-07 00:00:00 wolf      darkred
15 2020-08-07 00:00:00 wolf      rainbow
```